# Xamarin.Forms Branch.io getting deep link after install

Tags: xamarin.forms, branch.io

I've integrated Branch.io to my Xamarin.Forms app using IBranchBUOSessionInterface. I changed my App class signature to this:

```
 public partial class App : Application, IBranchBUOSessionInterface
```

and i have a method inside the class implementing the interface:

```
public async void InitSessionComplete(BranchUniversalObject buo, BranchLinkProperties blp)
```

Now deep linking works when i have the app installed, this method is invoked and i can get the data through the buo object metadata.

If the app is not installed, the user is correctly redirected to the relevant app store, but once the user downloads the app I expected the same method be invoked on first launch to retrieve the referral deeplink from branch automatically, but it doesnt.

Should i be using IBranchSessionInterface instead of IBranchBUOSessionInterface? I didnt understand their difference anyways.. Or should i be calling a method specifically for first launch? Since I only need this on first launch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following the example [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/xamarin-branch-deep-linking/blob/master/Examples/ios_example/Branch_Testbed_iOS/AppDelegate.cs), which uses IBranchBUOSessionInterface, deferred deep linking should work as well. If you are still running into issues, could you please write in to integrations@branch.io with your Branch key, AppDelegate.cs file, and test link. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, actually i think there's a problem with ios 11.2 and deferred deep links not working 100% (it says on branch website) and i was testing mostly on an iphone.. When i tested on an android device everything works perfect, as expected.. I'll see what i can do for ios.. Thanks!